# No Cells Found on IF condition

Tags: vba

I'm attempting to figure out how to handle the error "No Cells Found".
The idea is that it will filter down to what I want deleted and if there are rows delete them. If not move on.

I've been looking up other peoples solutions but what I've found they don't really meet the criteria I'm looking for and those that are close are similar to what I have.

I did attempt to setup an error handler with On Error Goto 0 but still get the error.

I'm not sure what I'm missing and think I need another set of eyes on my code.
Any help or push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!!

Code:

```
Private Sub cmdGoLive_Click()
Dim rngFiltered As Range
lrow as long

On Error Resume Next

With myWorkbook.Worksheets("qryGoLive")
    lrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'Filter by Color (Duplicates) then Filter by Offertype
    .Range("A2:P" & lrow).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=RGB(255, 0, 0), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
    .Range("A2:P" & lrow).AutoFilter Field:=16, Criteria1:="Promo"

'Delete Rows
Set rngFiltered = .Range("A2:P" & lrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Row
    
    If Not rngFiltered Is Nothing Then
        .Cells(1, 1).Offset(1, 0).Resize(lrow - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    Else
    End If

'Unfilter Offertype and then color
    myWorkbook.Worksheets("qryGoLive").ShowAllData
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: First of all, get rid of `.Row` in `.Range("A2:P" & lrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Row`.

Comment: Why are you using `.SpecialCells` a second time, instead of working with `rngFiltered`?